# Получить имя контроллера asp.net при помощи nameof

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [How to use C# nameof() with ASP.NET MVC
>   Url.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27444121/5752652)

Мне не нравится писать строки в выражениях вида:

```
Url.Action("ActionName", "Home")  <------ так работает
```

Хочется строгой типизации наподобие:

```
Url.Action(nameof(ActionName), nameof(HomeController)) <----- так не работает :(
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27444121/5752652

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант. Используйте метод расширения:

```
public static string UrlName(this Type controller)
{
  var name = controller.Name;
  return name.EndsWith("Controller") ? name.Substring(0, name.Length - 10) : name;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Url.Action(nameof(ActionName), typeof(HomeController).UrlName())
```

Второй вариант:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static string Action<T>(this Controller controller, string actionName)
        where T : Controller
    {
        var name = typeof(T).Name;
        string controllerName = name.EndsWith("Controller")
            ? name.Substring(0, name.Length - 10) : name;
        return controller.Url.Action(actionName, controllerName);
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
this.Action<HomeController>(nameof(ActionName));
```

Comment: Если вы конечно не используете area в своём проекте.